# Javascript: Create an array out of a string

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array out of a special string. The format is as follows:

> (a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j)))

The array should be like this:

> (a) | (b) | (c(d,e)) | (f(g(h,i,j)))

Using the `split()` function was not a good idea, as it gave me something like this:

> (a) | (b) | (c(d | e)) | (f(g(h | i | j)))

Any ideas?

Comment: I think if you choose `.split("),(")` it should work. Were you using .split(",") before?

Comment: How about splitting on `),` and then concatenating back the `)` on all elements but the last?

Comment: @MarouaGasmi Any chance the string will look like `(a),(b),(c(d,e),(f,g))` (so even `.split("),(")` will fail)? Or do you think @WarrenR 's comment is helpful enough to be an answer?

Comment: You just have to go poking hole in everyone's work, huh? :) @Passerby

Comment: @Passerby: We know only of one way the string can look like. So the answers are given in regards to that. We don't know any other ways the string might look like so why speculate? The rules aren't given, only the one example. So that's what we have to go with.

Comment: @WarrenR. OP's string looks non-intuiting, which _may_ hint various "malform" (e.g. is `(c,d)` allowed, or must it be `c(d,e)`?), so I was asking how "unexpected" the string can be; On the other hand, if your comment is sufficient, OP should ask you to post as an answer (so the "do you think...is helpful enough" phrase) instead of leaving a comment with upvotes.

Comment: @Passerby, I completely understand what you were doing there. I was a just little miffed that I didn't see it myself, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about counting the number of *open* parenthesis? If the count is zero, you're safe to split.

```
var
  input = '(a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j)))',
  i = 0,
  lim = input.length,
  output = [],
  count = 0,
  stack = [],
  c;

for (; i < lim; i += 1) {
  c = input.charAt(i);

  switch (c) {
    case '(':
      count += 1;
      break;

    case ')':
      count -= 1;
      break;

    case ',':
      if (count === 0) {
        output.push(stack.join(''));
        stack = [];
        continue;
      }
      break;
  }

  stack.push(c);
}

if (stack.length > 0) {
  output.push(stack.join(''));
}

console.log(output); // ["(a)", "(b)", "(c(d,e))", "(f(g(h,i,j)))"]
```

http://jsbin.com/otofog/1/

---

or alternatively (if you're not targeting IE < 9):

```
function mySplit(input) {
  var count = 0, output = [], stack;

  stack = input.split('').reduce(function (stack, c) {
    switch (c) {
      case '(': count += 1; break;
      case ')': count -= 1; break;
      case ',':
        if (count === 0) {
          output.push(stack.join(''));
          return [];
        }
    }

    stack.push(c);
    return stack;
  }, []);

  if (stack.length > 0) {
    output.push(stack.join(''));
  }

  return output;
}

console.log( mySplit('(a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j)))') );
```

http://jsbin.com/ohasuc/1/

Comment: I just made some changes : var lim = input.length;
var output = [];
var count = 0;
var stack = [];
var c;

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible short solution:

```
function strSplit(str, x) {
    return x = 0, str.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
        return c === "(" ? (x++, c) :
               c === ")" && i < a.length - 1 && --x === 0 ? c + "|" : c;
    }).split("|,");
}

strSplit("(a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j),k(l,m),n))");
// >> ["(a)", "(b)", "(c(d,e))", "(f(g(h,i,j),k(l,m),n))"]
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WRdAC/

---

To make the code more clear, here is the full-scale variant:

```
function strSplit(str) {
    var x = 0;
    return str.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
        if (c === "(") {
            x++;
        } else if (c === ")" && i < a.length - 1 && --x === 0) {
            return c + "|";
        }
        return c;
    }).split("|,");
}
```

Comment: Is that replacing commas with pipes?

Comment: I think he was just using the pipe character to delimit array elements rather than actually adding them into the string. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: +1 Note it will not work if the OP has something like `(a),(b),(c(d),(e))`

Comment: @WarrenR. Yes I believe this is true; the OP could then split on `"|"` afterward though

Comment: +1 for a code I can read without scrolling even on my phone... Please add some parentheses to make it clearer, though...

Comment: Good edit. Now, it's less a round flat bread of Middle Eastern origin to read.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var s = "(a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j)))";
var a = s.split("),");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
  a[i] = a[i] + ")";
```

More complex structures might require this:

```
var s = "(a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j),k(l,m),n))";
var a = s.split("),(");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
  a[i] = a[i] + ")";
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
  a[i] = "(" + a[i];
```

Comment: What if `(a),(b),(c(d,e)),(f(g(h,i,j),k(l,m),n))`?

Comment: @Passerby: Then the split would have to be `),(` and the concatenation would then be `)` on all elements but the last and `(` on all elements but the first.

Answer (score 0):

This function does exactly what you're looking for:

```
function parseStrToArr(str){
  var pairs = 0;
  var arr   = [];
  var chars = '';

  for(var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++){
    var char = str[i];

    switch(char){
      case '(': pairs++; break;
      case ')': pairs--; break;
    }

    if(!pairs){
      if(chars){
        arr.push(chars + char);
        chars = '';
      }
    }
    else{
      chars += char;
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

The key is to match up pairs of parenthesis. This algorithm will work even if you remove the commas.